# req.flash() result [ ]

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

So I have a problem when I want to show the message of `req.flash()`
Here is my code, [image]

```
 <%if(typeof message_success != "undefined" && message_success){%>
    <% console.log("msg", message_success) %>
    <% console.log("msgclocals", message_success) %>
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible mt-0 mb-1" id="success-alert">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
        <strong>Success!</strong> <%= message_success %>
    </div>
    <br>
<% } %>
```

I checked on `ejs` the `req.flash()` but the result is [ ], the result I want is "Success upload!". Is there any mistake in my codes?

Comment: Did you try to log messages.message_success or messages.success in ejs?

Comment: @HanhNguyen i tried to log to check the flash message but the result still empty.. i already try both but still empty.. i also check in router.get("/menu") the result is same.. idk where's the mistake..